# Everything in database gets updated instead of single row

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am building login system and i have added the update feature. but when i update the user profile from logged in account the whole database row gets updated.

I have this code

```
    include 'db.php';
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
if (!$_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "You must be logged in to use this section";
    header("location: error.php");
}
if (isset($_POST['uupdate'])) {
    $username = $_POST['uusername'];
    $email = $_POST['uemail'];
    if (isset($_POST['uusername'])) {
        try {


$query = $connect->prepare("UPDATE users SET username='$username' WHERE id = '$id'");
        $check = $query->fetch();
    $id = $check['id'];
        $query->execute(array($username));
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
        if (isset($_POST['uemail'])) {
        try {
        $query = $connect->prepare("UPDATE users SET email='$email' LIMIT 1");
        $query->execute(array($email));
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

i don't have any idea how to update user using the id. If anyone has solution please share.

Comment: You probably want to add a `WHERE` clause to the query…?!

Comment: didn't understood what you are syaing

Comment: What you need is basic SQL knowledge… you want some form of `UPDATE ... WHERE id = $something`. Have you ever heard of `WHERE` in SQL?

Comment: yo i know so you mean to say that i have to query the database first then i have to get the id row. which i will use in where clause

Comment: No, you just need to specify *which* row you want to update. That doesn't mean you need to query it first. `UPDATE` without a `WHERE` applies to *all rows*. `UPDATE ... LIMIT 1` also applies to all rows, but it will stop after having updated one row.

Comment: what information i have to store in variable $something

Comment: Whatever you need to uniquely identify the row you want to update.

Comment: can't get you please will you post an answer

Comment: will you please check the above updated code, am i doing it right

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you are missing the `where` condition, so all the entries are updated.
You have to explicitly tell which row to update.

Probably both username and email are unique, so, let's say that `$old_email` and `$old_username` are the old values for the user you are updating, then you should change the queries to:

```
UPDATE users SET username='$username' WHERE username ='$old_username'
```

and

```
UPDATE users SET email='$email' WHERE email ='$old_email'
```

respectively.

Reference for the where condition [in the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
$connect->prepare("UPDATE users SET username='$username' LIMIT 1");
```

There is the WHERE clause missing. You need to add WHERE id="$id" and you have to get the $id from somewhere, maybe $_SESSIOn of $_POST, but that part of your architecture is not visible here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which row of the table you want to update. You can do so using a `WHERE` clause. You would typically use the `id` of the user in the `WHERE` clause.

**Example:**

To change the email address of the user that has username `Bob`, to `newemail@mail.com`, you could use the following query:

`UPDATE users SET email='newemail@mail.com' WHERE username='Bob'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to **define which row** to update:

**You can use an ID:**

```
$query = $connect->prepare("UPDATE users SET email='$email' WHERE id='{$id}' LIMIT 1");
```

**Or use username:**

```
$query = $connect->prepare("UPDATE users SET email='$email' WHERE username='{$username}' LIMIT 1");
```

You are also using the **prepare/execute function wrong**. To bind the parameters safely to the query you can do it like this:

```
$query = $connect->prepare("UPDATE users SET email=:email WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1");
$query->execute(array('id'=>$id, 'email'=>$email));
```

**PHP 7>**
In PHP 7 or higher you can change array() to [] like this:

```
$query->execute(['id'=>$id, 'email'=>$email]);
```

Comment: i used this type of array in login.php but it didn't worked for me so using that way